# Проблема с циклом while true

Tags: python, время, kivy, while

Проблема с циклом while true. Это програма которая отправляет на определённый номер телефона кучу сообщений и когда я её запускаю ввожу данные и нажимаю Запустить спам, она зависает намертво.

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

    from twilio.rest import Client
    import time

    account = "ACc6eb7f9244dfef46ec19e38b37b67e79"
    token = "2a5a25361734e7be07590d3005008efe"
    client = Client(account, token)

    class SpamApp(App):

        def btn_pressed(self, *args):
            while True:
                message = client.messages.create(to=nom, from_="+18318300263",
                                         body=text)
                time.sleep(1)

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.input_nom = TextInput(hint_text="Номер получателя...", multiline=False)
            self.input_nom.bind(text=self.on_text)
            self.input_text = TextInput(hint_text="Текст сообщения...", multiline=False)
            self.input_text.bind(text=self.on_text)

        def on_text(self, *args):
            global nom
            global text
            nom = self.input_nom.text
            text = self.input_text.text


        def build(self):
            al = AnchorLayout()
            bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=[.4, .4])

            bl.add_widget(self.input_nom)
            bl.add_widget(self.input_text)
            btn = Button(text = 'Запустить спам')
            btn.bind(on_press=self.btn_pressed)
            bl.add_widget(btn)

            al.add_widget(bl)
            return al

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        SpamApp().run()
```

Comment: В обработчиках `GUI` нельзя делать циклы, `sleep` и т.д., интерфейс именно что повиснет. Причём это в любом языке программирования и фреймворке так в принципе. Я `Kivy` не знаю, нужно разбираться как там отдельный поток для этого сделать или что.

Comment: так нет никакой проблемы, все работает как написано в коде - цикл запускается и бесконечно выполняется.